# openSUSE - Repository 'XY' is invalid - change repository to load from internet instead from medium

Tags: opensuse, zypper

I try to install some PHP modules:

```
zypper install php7.0-gd php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-curl php7.0-intl php7.0-xsl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-openssl php7.0-zip php7.0-soap
```

**Output:**

```
Failed to mount cd:///?devices=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-VMware_Virtual_IDE_CDROM_Drive_10000000000000000001 on /var/tmp/AP_0xgQO1rM: Mounting media failed (mount: /var/tmp/AP_0xgQO1rM: no medium found on /dev/sr0.)
Please insert medium [] #1 and type 'y' to continue or 'n' to cancel the operation. [yes/no] (no): no
Error building the cache:
[openSUSE-Leap-15.0-1|cd:///?devices=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-VMware_Virtual_IDE_CDROM_Drive_10000000000000000001] Valid metadata not found at specified URL
Warning: Skipping repository 'openSUSE-Leap-15.0-1' because of the above error.
Some of the repositories have not been refreshed because of an error.
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'php7.0-curl' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'php7.0-curl' found.
'php7.0-gd' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'php7.0-gd' found.
'php7.0-intl' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'php7.0-intl' found.
'php7.0-mbstring' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'php7.0-mbstring' found.
'php7.0-mcrypt' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'php7.0-mcrypt' found.
'php7.0-openssl' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'php7.0-openssl' found.
'php7.0-soap' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'php7.0-soap' found.
'php7.0-xsl' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'php7.0-xsl' found.
'php7.0-zip' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'php7.0-zip' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

I think there is something wrong with my repositories. It tries to load the repository from the disk (*cd:///?devices=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-VMware_Virtual_IDE_CDROM_Drive_10000000000000000001*) instead of from the internet. But the disc is not inserted anymore and I can't since it is a virtual machine in my company and the admin is in vaccation.

**zypper lr -uP**:

```
#  | Alias                     | Name                                    | Enabled | GPG Check | Refresh | Priority | URI
---+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-1      | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-1                    | Yes     | ( p) Yes  | No      |   99     | cd:///?devices=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-VMware_Virtual_IDE_CDROM_Drive_10000000000000000001
 2 | packman.inode.at-suse     | Packman Repository                      | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes     |   99     | http://packman.inode.at/suse/openSUSE_Leap_15.0/
 3 | repo-debug                | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Debug                | No      | ----      | ----    |   99     | http://download.opensuse.org/debug/distribution/leap/15.0/repo/oss/
 4 | repo-debug-non-oss        | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Debug-Non-Oss        | No      | ----      | ----    |   99     | http://download.opensuse.org/debug/distribution/leap/15.0/repo/non-oss/
 5 | repo-debug-update         | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update-Debug         | No      | ----      | ----    |   99     | http://download.opensuse.org/debug/update/leap/15.0/oss/
 6 | repo-debug-update-non-oss | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update-Debug-Non-Oss | No      | ----      | ----    |   99     | http://download.opensuse.org/debug/update/leap/15.0/non-oss/
 7 | repo-non-oss              | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Non-Oss              | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes     |   99     | http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/15.0/repo/non-oss/
 8 | repo-oss                  | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Oss                  | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes     |   99     | http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/15.0/repo/oss/
 9 | repo-source               | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Source               | No      | ----      | ----    |   99     | http://download.opensuse.org/source/distribution/leap/15.0/repo/oss/
10 | repo-source-non-oss       | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Source-Non-Oss       | No      | ----      | ----    |   99     | http://download.opensuse.org/source/distribution/leap/15.0/repo/non-oss/
11 | repo-update               | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update               | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes     |   99     | http://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/15.0/oss/
12 | repo-update-non-oss       | openSUSE-Leap-15.0-Update-Non-Oss       | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes     |   99     | http://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/15.0/non-oss/
```

How can I change the repository so that it loads from the internet?

I know I can modify an existing repo with `zypper modifyrepo`, but how can I modify the URI and where can I find the correct URI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it is impossible to rename the URI.

So I removed the old repository with `zypper rr openSUSE-Leap-15.0-1` and created new ones - I created both oss and non-oss, but im not sure what oss and non-oss refers to:

```
zypper ar -p 1 http://download.opensuse.org/debug/distribution/leap/15.2/repo/non-oss/ openSUSE-Leap-15.2_non-oss

zypper ar -p 2 http://download.opensuse.org/debug/distribution/leap/15.2/repo/oss/ openSUSE-Leap-15.2_oss
```

You can find all repos here: http://download.opensuse.org/

I also had to change the install command, because the package names were wrong:

```
zypper install php7-gd php7-mcrypt php7-curl php7-intl php7-xsl php7-mbstring php7-openssl php7-zip php7-soap
```

**EDIT:** But be cautious! As you can see I changed from **openSUSE-Leap-15.0-1** to **openSUSE-Leap-15.2**. As I executed `zypper update` it also updated PHP from 7.2 to 7.3 which caused some bugs in magento 2. Better stay on your version if you don't want to upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

If one repository points to a disk/url that does not exist anymore, simply remove or disable that repository:

disable:

```
zypper mr -d openSUSE-Leap-15.0-1
```

remove:

```
zypper rr openSUSE-Leap-15.0-1
```

for the rest I would strongly recommend you to stay with the repositories of your own distribution. Using packages from other (more recent) distributions might cause dependency trouble and you might end up half upgrading your system. In that case, why not upgrade your whole os?